# How do I test authenticated pages with Cypress in a react app that uses firebase for social logins?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, cypress

When I need to test something on an authenticated page, I use the following before hook:

```
beforeEach('login', () => {
    cy.visit('/protected', {
      onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
        win.localStorage.setItem(user1.key, user1.token);
      },
    });
    cy.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
      console.error(err);
      return false;
    });
  });
```

`user.1` is imported from '../fixtures/testUsers' where I copy and pasted the key and value pairs in browser storage.

To get the key-value pairs, I login with a social account then I open the `Application` tab in dev tools, open up `Local Storage` in the left-hand side panel and then copy the key and value that has the string `firebase:authUser...` in it.

It works.

More importantly, it lets me login in with two different accounts, gets two different sets of user keys and then simulates interactions between them in my tests.

But it feels hacky, to say the least.

Is there anything wrong with this approach? Is there a 'proper' way to do this?

Comment: Have you figured this out?

Comment: Nope. Nothing better than this hacky solution. I gave up asking in gitter. I also stopped using cypress with firebase because there is no support for fetch https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/687